# Can you show file size in BYTES, not KB in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

I thought there was a way to show filesize in actual bytes in Windows Explorer's Details View, rather than KB/MB/GB.  Can't find it though.

Comment: I have a slightly different question: I'm more interested in the automatic display showing bytes when the file is less than 1KB. For years, I've been misled into thinking that some of my files are as big as 1KB, when in fact they are only a few hundred bytes. Do you know if this alternative question has been asked before?

Comment: [Can bytes be displayed **only** when the file is less than 1KB?](https://superuser.com/q/1569825/386552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explorer won't do this as far as I know. I use [xplorer²](http://www.zabkat.com/) for a substitute and it will show file sizes in bytes:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same problem with Windows Explorer. If you do not wish to download any add-on or software to view your files. One simple way is to open command prompt and view the files with `dir`  command.

1. Click on the filepath of explorer:
   [image]
2. Type `cmd`, press Enter. The command prompt will show up with your current directory.
   [image]
3. Type `dir` to view all files (with size in bytes) in current directory.
   [image]

Comment: This isn't very useful if you need to sort Windows Explorer search results (e.g. all text files containing "Superman") on size.

Comment: `cmd` could do more things than you could in Windows Explorer. Anyway OP only asked for the size in bytes and my solution address to that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 3rd party tool [Size In Bytes](https://www.smartftp.com/sizeinbytes) which makes Windows Explorer display the file size in bytes.

Comment: According to the Size In Bytes info page, a valid SmartFTP license is required, and that's about $80 for the cheapest version (last I checked). Nevertheless, this license requirement does not seem to be enforced, at least not for random individual users; I've been using this Explorer extension for many years without issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) will do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FreeCommander](http://freecommander.com). It is freeware and you can view the size in bytes, kB, MB, or "Auto":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and constructive answer, Superuser benefits from members like you.

Comment: I'm more interested in the automatic display showing bytes when it is less than 1kB. I wonder if FreeCommander does this, since this is not obvious from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is yet another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The following example creates bat files to rename some files to embed the size in the name (file explorer shows that) and a 2nd to undo the change when you are finished.

@for %i in (xx*log*) do @echo rename %i %i--%~zi >> tmp1.bat

@for %i in (xx*log*) do @echo rename %i--%~zi %i >> tmp2.bat

Not very general purpose, but I found it useful when cleaning up a bunch of redundant log files.

Comment: What question are you answering?