# Is there a free Windows Explorer (XP) replacement that is able to display file sizes to 1 byte precision?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-management, software-rec

The reason for the question is this:  I was trying to find the location of a file and the only thing about it I knew was the exact size.  So I search for all the files in the top of the folder tree and down, and sort the results by filesize, but I still can't identify the file because there are hundreds with a filesize of "123k".

I started to wade through the myriad of explorer replacements but after installing the first couple and finding they don't do that, I got lazy.

So specifically:

Is there a free Windows explorer replacement with a similar "find files" facility that can display the file sizes of the search results to a precision of one byte.

Being able to display the sizes to one byte in the normal folder view would also be useful, but not as useful as it would be if it also had the same file searching ability as XP's native explorer.

Comment: Question already asked and recommendations given at https://superuser.com/questions/178391/can-you-show-file-size-in-bytes-not-kb-in-windows-explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not part of windows explorer, but powershell does this by default (it is available for XP [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7217)).

If you want to search by the length field it is pretty simple just do:

`Get-ChildItem pathToSearch | Where-Object{$_.Length -eq size}`

Note that you must replace `pathToSearch` and `size` with the appropriate text. To make the search recursive, add `-Recurse`

Comment: Hmmmm. Thanks @soandos.  Not quite what I was looking for.  More after an app to take the place of Explorer, but offering display of the exact filesize.  You have renewed my interest in PowerShell however, as a replacement for batch files.

Comment: If all you wanted was to search though, wouldn't it me the same?

Comment: Point conceded.  Looks like there is nothing like what I want.  You get the tick.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a replacement for Explorer; you can use the [FolderSize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) shell-extension. You can configure its Control Panel applet to display sizes in bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes. It also shows the actual, contained size of folders. You may have to specifically show the *Folder Size* column for search results the first time, but then you can see the sizes of the results down to the byte.