# How can I get Windows Explorer to display file sizes in bytes, when the size is less than 1KB?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management

In Windows Explorer, if I have a file with a size smaller than 1KB (for example, a text file of 100 bytes), the application nevertheless displays the file size as 1KB. This is annoying, as I don't want to be misled into thinking the file is much larger than it actually is.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Display the exact file size in bytes in Windows Explorer >>>>>>https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/sizeinbytes

Comment: No, my question is different to that one. I'm interested in the automatic display showing bytes only when the file is less than 1KB.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

No one but Microsoft can modify Windows Explorer. Your only option is to use a
third-party file manager.

See a list of such alternatives with reviews in the article
[Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm).

This list doesn't contain one of my favorites :
[Altap Salamander  Freeware](https://www.altap.cz/).

Comment: https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/sizeinbytes

Comment: Thanks. The software at the top of the list in the article you linked is FreeCommander. [Do you know of a file manager that can display the file sizes with binary prefixes?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/75429/61548)

Comment: Product recommendation are out of subject here, so I can't do more than the above.

Answer (score -1):

SmartFTP has such a function, but the display will be in bytes, not dynamically, depending on the size (b, kb, mb or Gb)

[image: SmartFTP comparison]